# Dimension (Name) column missing from dataframe after groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSMhq.png)

and this code to group by

avg_loc = df.groupby('Last_Name_passer').agg({'x_origin':['mean'], 'y_origin':['mean', 'count']})
avg_loc.columns = ['x', 'y', 'count']
avg_loc

and this is the result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uq5q.png)

However, when I call the `df.columns` `(avg_loc.columns)`, the player name (dimension) is not actually there in the df. All I have is the mean x and y and count columns.

`Index(['x', 'y', 'count'], dtype='object')`

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you make a small example of the data, such that it is possible to replicate what you are showing here?

Comment: Sure - please see edited post above.

Comment: add `avg_loc = avg_loc.reset_index()` after your solution